# A variant of strong ideals, is it consistent?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Is it consistent relative to large cardinals that there is a precipitous ideal on $\omega_1$ forcing a generic elementary embedding $j : V \to M \subseteq V[G]$, such that $j(\omega_1) = \omega_n^V$ for some $n > 2$?

A little background:  The first thought may be start with a measurable $\kappa$ for which $2^\kappa = \kappa^{+n}$ for some large $n$.  Collapse $\kappa$ to $\omega_1$ and look at the ideal induced by the dual of the measure.  But it is easy to show that $2^\kappa < j(\kappa) < (2^\kappa)^+$.  In order to get an ideal forcing $j(\omega_1) = \omega_2$, usually stronger assumptions are used to produce a pre-saturated ideal.  It is known how we can get ideals forcing $j(\omega_1) = \omega_n$ for whatever $n$, but these are normal ideals on something like $\mathcal P_{\omega_1}(\omega_{n-1})$.

Comment: Not being fluent in these type of arguments, what is the "obvious difficulty" (e.g. why won't taking some $j(\kappa)=\kappa^{+4}$ and collapsing $\kappa$ to be $\omega_1$ in a way where the embedding can be extended generically work)?

Comment: This might work, but what large cardinal assumption gets such an embedding?

Comment: I don't know. What large cardinals gives you $j(\kappa)=\kappa^{+4}$? Something like $\kappa^{+4}$-supercompact? Or something like that?

Comment: Typically the target of $\kappa$ is not a cardinal, unless you're using a very strong assumption where it's actually inaccessible.

Comment: What about $j^2$, where $j$ is a 2-huge embedding?

Comment: @SeanCox I don't follow

Comment: I think that @Sean means that if $\kappa$ is a 2-huge cardinal, then the embedding sends $\kappa$ to a cardinal, and the iterated embedding also maps it to a cardinal. Although I don't see how collapsing $\kappa$ to be $\omega_1$ you'd get the embedding to reach "only" to $\kappa^{+4}$...